# Finding Nash Equilibrium for 2x3 game *with no Pure NE*

Tags: game-theory, nash-equilibrium

There's no pure NE nor dominated strategies and I am struggling to solve for the MSNE  when 2x3 matrix like this... 
$$\begin{array}{|c|c|c|c|}\hline & C & D & E \\ \hline A & 0,10 & 10,0 & -5,7\\ \hline B & 10,0 & 0,10 & -5,7 \\ \hline\end{array}$$

Answer (score 1):

Suppose player $1$ chooses $A$ with probability $p$, and $2$ chooses $C$ and $D$ with probability $q$ and $s$ respectively. Then $E(\pi_2)=10qp+10s(1-p)+7(1-q-s)$, and solving the first order conditions yields that a mixed strategy equilibrium must satisfy $p=3/10$ or $p=7/10$. In both cases, option $E$ weakly dominates options $C$ and $D$ for player $2$, so any strategy where player $1$ chooses $A$ with $p\in[3/10,7/10]$ and player $2$ chooses $E$ with probability $1$, is a mixed strategy Nash equilibrium.

Comment: Would "Player 1 plays a mixed strategy (1/2,1/2) and Player 2 plays a mixed strategy (1/2,1/2,0)" be a mixed strategy Nash Equilibrium?

Comment: In that case, player $2$ has an expected profit of $5$, which is dominated by strategy $E$, which yields an expected profit of $7$. So, the answer is no.

Comment: Ahhh I see... so Player 1 plays mixed strategy (1/2,1/2); Player 2 plays _E_